# How to rename series episode files in folders to foldername using batch file

Tags: shell-script, find, rename

Looking for script or ? in terminal..

I have a directory named tv series with many series in it, example folder 24 hours - 24 episodes, in format 
S01E01.mkv-- S01E24.mkv. 
Would like to have it named after the  folder it's in /24/....
24.S01E01.mkv, 24.S01E02.mkv, 24.S01E03.mkv

Thank you

Comment: yes found it thx,      mmv -n "*.mkv*" "24.#1.mkv"